# Outputting SVG from an asset field inside a matrix field with svg()

Tags: assets-field, svg

I've set up an asset field inside a matrix field where a user can upload SVG icons, but I'm having trouble outputting them using the svg() function.

```
{# Correctly shows the path #}
{{ callout.icon[0].url }}

{# Correctly displays the SVG within an image tag #}
<img src = "{{ callout.icon[0].url }}" alt=""  />

{# No output #}
{{ svg(callout.icon[0].url) }}
{{ svg(callout.icon) }}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with the svg() function? Other than being inside a matrix field, what I'm doing doesn't seem to differ from the example in [the documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#svg). I'm trying to avoid using any plugins if at all possible.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error in the logs? Just out of interest have you tried using `.one()` instead of `[0]` i.e. `{{ svg(callout.icon.one().url) }}`

Comment: Just tried. Without svg() it correctly displays the path, but with svg() there's no ouput. Are the logs in /craft/stroates/logs/ ? If so, I checked there and searched all the .log.1, .log.2, .log.3 files, for "svg" but nothing came up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, think I know what's wrong – you want to select the first asset, but not its url. E.g.

```
{{ svg(callout.icon.one()) }}
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thank you so much :)